# Limit on query rows

Tags: apex, soql, limitexception

I am trying to write a trigger to update the manager on the user record. So, I created a custom text field which would be populated with the user's manager Name and I'd then fetch the managerID based on the name and update the Manager ID.

```java
public static void UpdateManager(list<User> triggerNew, Map<Id,User> triggerOldMap, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isInsert){
    Set<String> MgrName = new Set<String>();
    Map<String, Id> MgrMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(User u :Trigger.new){
        if(isInsert || (isUpdate && u.ManagerName__c != triggeroldMap.get(u.Id).ManagerName__c && u.ManagerName__c !=null){
            MgrName.add(u.ManagerName__c);
        }
    }
    for(User usr :[select Id, Name from user where Name IN :MgrName]){
        MgrMap.put(usr.Name,usr.Id);
    }
    for(User user : Trigger.new){
        if(MgrMap.containskey(user.ManagerName__c)){
            user.ManagerId = MgrMap.get(user.ManagerName__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001
If I were to limit it to 1, then could I use the below instead of the code above?

```
User usr = new user();

for(String MgrName : mgnm ){
    usr = [select Id, Name from user where Name IN :MgrName LIMIT 1];

    MgrMap.put(usr.Name, usr.Id);
}
```

But writing a query within a for loop. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Where and how are you calling `UpdateManager`? I don't see anything in your code that would cause it to run in a loop, since you are neither calling yourself nor making dmls

Comment: Can you clarify with an [edit] the verbatim text of the error? Running a query 49k _times_ is not possible, but you can get a Query Rows limit exception at 50,000 rows. (Although I can't see how that would easily happen here).

Comment: If `ManagerName__c` you won't be able to check if it changed.

Comment: Using appropriate indentation and whitespace helps other people read your code (as does applying the appropriate formatting here). I've done this for you this time, but expect you will do it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is presumably this line:

```
if(isInsert || (isUpdate && u.ManagerName__c != triggeroldMap.get(u.Id).ManagerName__c && u.ManagerName__c !=null){
```

If ManagerName__c is null, you'll end up with an empty set, which would probably query all records in the database. Oops. Instead, check if it's null always:

```
if(u.ManagerName__c != null && (isInsert || u.ManagerName__c != triggeroldMap.get(u.Id).ManagerName__c)) {
```

Also, you need to check to make sure the manager is an active user:

```
for(User usr :[select Id, Name from user where Name IN :MgrName and IsActive = true]){
```

Finally, if the name has changed, you probably want to null out the value and reset it. This makes sure that if the user isn't a valid user, you'll not end up with the old value being retained:

```
if(u.ManagerName__c != null && (isInsert || u.ManagerName__c != triggeroldMap.get(u.Id).ManagerName__c)) {
  u.ManagerId = null;
```

Comment: I added an additional line to check the set wasn't empty before the query line : if (!MgrName.isEmpty()). But I will try adding the check to see the not null condition on the ManagerName.

Comment: @DavidReed : The error is Error Message System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001. When I checked the debug logs, I see this particular query had run about 49000 times.

Comment: @Sergio Alcocer : This is being called from the user trigger <br>                                                                                    trigger  StandardUserTrigger on User (before update, before insert)                                  {
StandardUserHandler.UpdateManager(trigger.new, trigger.OldMap, trigger.isUpdate, trigger.isInsert);
}

Comment: @Priya Please edit your question, don't add this information in comments. It is not possible for your query to run 49,000 times.